# Who are these red cloaked figures?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

Does anyone know if these red cloaked figures seen standing behind [Zyn Javeb](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Zyn_Javeb) have an official name?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

These functionaries appear to be advisors to the Port Adminstrator [Tion Medon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tion_Medon) who acts as the city's governor, not to be confused with the [Utapau Committee](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Utapauan_Committee), which represents the entire planet.

> Each city-state has its own government and administration, and each is
> overseen by a single leader (known as the Master of Port
> Administration) who has **an advisory council** to assist in making
> important decisions.
>
> <sub><sup>Saga Edition Web Enhancement: The Pau'ans</sup></sub>

The Pau'ans aren't really mentioned in any detail in either novelisation, nor do they have canonical names, other than [Zyn Javeb](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Zyn_Javeb) and [Lampay Fay](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lampay_Fay).

Answer (score 1):

According to Wookieepedia, they are [**Pau'an Warriors**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Pau%27an_Warrior). They were the infantry of Utapau, and instead of using blasters and energy shields, they used ancient ceremonial armor and bladed weapons. They rode dactillions and helped fight against the Separatists in the Battle of Utapau.

Comment: You (and wookieepedia) are mistaken. [These](https://scontent-yyz1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.135.1080.1080a/s640x640/42431976_678760749189857_3864751438337906669_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-yyz1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=105&_nc_ohc=Rnb_lVFi30kAX9iqSWa&oh=cb6e31949dd6e9de06d23d805bdc2729&oe=5F0E9DCE) are [Pau'an warriors](https://swfanon.fandom.com/wiki/Bane_Frodo).